# How to inject dependency in FIlter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters

**Student instance is coming as null in MyFilter class via autowiring.

Also tried using WebApplicationContext but still it's not working**

```
@WebFilter("/*)
class MyFilter implements Filter{

@Autowired Student student;

@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    //student instance is coming as null here.
    student.doSomething();

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

//Also tried by overriding init() of filter 
@Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        log.INFO("Filter initialized");
        
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext =
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext());
        this.student= webApplicationContext.getBean(Student.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `@Component` annotation?

Comment: instead of normal `filter`, you can use `HandlerInterceptor` as it is spring component and more powerful than normal filter and do the same job for more info this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

Comment: more powerful? it is said interceptor cannot change request/response, while filter can.

Comment: Tried with @Component but the Dependency is not getting injected in the Filter